# OpenSessionInViewFilter doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, spring, open-session-in-view

Please somebody rescure me, I cannot lazy load my class, I tried to write Open Session In View strategy, but it seems not to work.
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
           org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

Here is my spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/spring/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pdfViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
     <property name="order" value="1"/>
     <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/simpleviews.xml"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
        <property name="autodetect" value="false" />
        <property name="assembler">
            <bean id="jmxAssembler"
                class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
                <property name="attributeSource">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="**" />
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="messages" />



    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <!-- some properties -->
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>pl.edm.taskcards.spring</value>
                <value>pl.raban.resource.spring</value>
                <value>pl.raban.common.dictionary.spring</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

My BookDAO.class:

```
@Component
public class BookDAO {

    @Bean
    public BookDAO bookDAO(){
        return new BookDAO();
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    public void save(Book book){
        hibernateTemplate.save(book);
    }


    public void update(Book book){
        book.setModifyTime(new Date());
        hibernateTemplate.update(book);
    }

    public void delete(Book book){
        hibernateTemplate.delete(book);
    }

    public List<Book> list(String content, String status, String dprt, String wdz){
        Session session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Book.class);
        return list;

    }
    public Book getbookById(int id){
        return (Book)hibernateTemplate.get(Book.class, id);
    }   
}
```

and my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/book.do", method=RequestMethod.GET )
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView viewGET(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        Book book = bookDAO.getbookById(id);
        modelMap.addAttribute("book", book);
        return new ModelAndView("book", modelMap);
    }
```

When I want to go on my book.jsp (book.do in browser) site, I got exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: pl.edm.taskcards.spring.Book.ChapterList, no session or session was closed
    org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380)
    org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:372)
    org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:365)
    org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:108)
    org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:366)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:242)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:173)
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:271)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.spring.kartaZadan_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(kartaZadan_jsp.java:1861)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.spring.kartaZadan_jsp._jspService(kartaZadan_jsp.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Comment: Do you use Hibernate as JPA Provider, or do you use the HibernateSession?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your filter configuration to:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
       org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I dunno about the original poster, but that just fixed my problem.  Four hours of searching for a solution has finally ended!